# SonarLint Eclipse plugin version error

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

When I try to connect to SonarQube server, an error is occured saying:

> The following plugins do not meet the required minimum versions,
>   please upgrade them: java (installed: 3.4, minimum: 3.8).

But as of the SonarLint

> http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/ : and "June 3, 2016 - We released
>   version 2.1.0 of SonarLint for Eclipse with extended support of
>   SonarQube 4.5.4+ ",

the latest version is 2.1 which I have already installed. My SonarQube server is 4.5.4. Have I missed something here or any solution please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are minimum versions for the SonarQube server and for each analyzer plugin.

Your SonarQube server should be ok, but you need to install a more recent Java analyzer plugin (version >= 3.8) in the SonarQube server.

More information about the Java analyzer: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava

Comment: Thanks Duarte. But I cant find any plugin whose version is >=3.8. Max is 2.1 as I mentioned in my question. Is there any Link to download a plugin : version >=3.8 please ?

Comment: Check here: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin. Don't forget to check the compatibility between the Java Plugin and your SonarQube server. The latest one is not compatible with SonarQube 4.5.4.

Comment: Any link where has the archives and mentioning the supported SonarQube server ? I read through official site, but couldn't find. May be I have missed.

Comment: Click over "More versions", which is just above the current version number.